# installing easydict in bundled Python 3.5 in Blender 2.79a in Ubuntu 22.04 using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, pip, blender

I am not sure if this is a fixable error in Ubuntu 22.04? Blender 2.79a is the non-negotiable here but I am open to using older versions of Ubuntu in docker. Originally, [pvnet-rendering repo][1] used Ubuntu 16.04 which is now EOL.

```
(pvnet-rendering) (base) mona@ada:~/pvnet-rendering$ pip install easydict
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mona/pvnet-rendering/pvnet-rendering/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/mona/pvnet-rendering/pvnet-rendering/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 272, in run
    with self._build_session(options) as session:
  File "/home/mona/pvnet-rendering/pvnet-rendering/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 69, in _build_session
    if options.cache_dir else None
  File "/home/mona/blender-2.79a-linux-glibc219-x86_64/2.79/python/lib/python3.5/posixpath.py", line 89, in join
    genericpath._check_arg_types('join', a, *p)
  File "/home/mona/blender-2.79a-linux-glibc219-x86_64/2.79/python/lib/python3.5/genericpath.py", line 143, in _check_arg_types
    (funcname, s.__class__.__name__)) from None
TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'int'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mona/pvnet-rendering/pvnet-rendering/bin/pip", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/mona/pvnet-rendering/pvnet-rendering/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 233, in main
    return command.main(cmd_args)
  File "/home/mona/pvnet-rendering/pvnet-rendering/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 251, in main
    timeout=min(5, options.timeout)) as session:
  File "/home/mona/pvnet-rendering/pvnet-rendering/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 69, in _build_session
    if options.cache_dir else None
  File "/home/mona/blender-2.79a-linux-glibc219-x86_64/2.79/python/lib/python3.5/posixpath.py", line 89, in join
    genericpath._check_arg_types('join', a, *p)
  File "/home/mona/blender-2.79a-linux-glibc219-x86_64/2.79/python/lib/python3.5/genericpath.py", line 143, in _check_arg_types
    (funcname, s.__class__.__name__)) from None
TypeError: join() argument must be str or bytes, not 'int'
```

Also, steps to get to this point:

```
(base) mona@ada:~$ wget https://download.blender.org/release/Blender2.79/blender-2.79a-linux-glibc219-x86_64.tar.bz2
(base) mona@ada:~$ tar -xvf blender-2.79a-linux-glibc219-x86_64.tar.bz2 
(base) mona@ada:~$ git clone https://github.com/zju3dv/pvnet-rendering
(base) mona@ada:~$ cd pvnet-rendering/
/home/mona/blender-2.79a-linux-glibc219-x86_64/2.79/python/bin/python3.5m -m venv pvnet-rendering
source pvnet-rendering/bin/activate
```

The instructions states:

```
(pvnet-rendering) (base) mona@ada:~/pvnet-rendering$ python  run.py --type rendering
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from config import cfg
  File "/home/mona/pvnet-rendering/config.py", line 1, in <module>
    from easydict import EasyDict
ImportError: No module named 'easydict'
```

Hence I am trying to install the easydict package.
[1]: https://github.com/zju3dv/pvnet-rendering

Comment: tell the project owner to include their `requirements.txt` file

Comment: @drum so far I didn't get answer on the rest of my questions that's why I asked this here